# Record which timeline created an activity

Tags: civicase

I want to record which timeline created a given activity.

The purpose for this is so, at a later date, I can see all the activities created by a particular timeline for a particular case.

With that list, I want to be able to easily change dates for activities that have not yet occurred for that timeline.

Maybe a process for that already exists? Any hints on how to implement it if not?

Thanks in advance for any help. John.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a workaround but you can create activity types specific to each timeline and then include the name of the timeline in the activity type label, e.g. if you have timelines named A and B then you could have activity types labelled:

`A - Phone Call
A - Fill out requisition
...
B - Phone Call
B - Fill out requisition
...`

Alternatively the add timeline feature will create dates relative to whatever offset you have in your config for that timeline, so you could have an "anchor" activity type which you create just before you add a timeline, and then in the timeline config you say make the offsets relative to that activity type. You'd have to rejig your timelines to match that workflow.